# ListView stretching to the bottom of the container, how can I prevent this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have the following layout with a `ListView`, which is stretching to the to the bottom of the parent container, even though I've specified that it should `wrap_content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLogs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="System Logs"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblLogs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEmailLogs"
        android:text="Email Logs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is causing the `Button` at the bottom to overlap the `ListView`, as depicted here:

[image]

How can I prevent the ListView from going all the way to the bottom, so that the button won't overlap it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the layout to `LinearLayout` and add `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLogs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="System Logs"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblLogs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEmailLogs"
        android:text="Email Logs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that's another way of doing this, the solution is karan's answer

Comment: Even in the context of a LinearLayout? I thought `layout_above` applied only to RelativeLayout... though, considering my question *has* RelativeLayout, you might have a point! I'll review shortly.

Comment: i said *that's another way of doing it* :)

Answer (score 3):

try using in listview this

```
  android:layout_above="@id/btnEmailLogs"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="7dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblLogs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="System Logs"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblLogs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnEmailLogs"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEmailLogs"
    android:text="Email Logs"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this to handle through code ::

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

int windowheight=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

int yourbuttonheight= get_your_button_height;

lp.height = windowheight- yourbuttonheight;

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.btnEmailLogs);
listView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Allthe best .